# Python discount rate of 2 items plus tax program not outputting correctly

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a program that inputs `2` items, applies a `25%` discount and adds a `8.25%` tax rate on the total discounted items price however I keep getting a wrong output.

It works with certain numbers such as `5 + 3` but doesn't come out correctly with `8.75 + 25.99`.

```
first_item = int(float(input("Price of 1st item: ")))

second_item = int(float(input("Price of 2nd item: ")))

discount = (first_item + second_item) *.25

discounted_items = (first_item + second_item) - discount

tax = discounted_items *.0825

final_pay = discounted_items + tax

print("You pay ", final_pay)
```

expected result with `8.75 + 25.99` is `28.204537` but I keep getting `26.7918`.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert your input from `str` to `float` it's great, but when you convert that again to an `int`, you lose the fractional part (`.xxx`), and so you lose precision, you didn't see this problem with `3` and `5` because they're already integer, and so nothing is lost, so just keep your input `float`:

```
first_item = float(input("Price of 1st item: "))
second_item = float(input("Price of 2nd item: "))
```